# Git: Two local clones of the same repository synchronized between them, both in the same branch

Tags: git, git-worktree

I'm working with a repository that has two different lines of development. Therefore, I have **two local clones** of that **same repo** in my PC. There are some added folders on each of the clones. Those extra folders are gitignored, and are different in each clone. They are for configuring the different SDKs needed in each case.

Time to time I have to do developments in one clone that affect the other clone too (modifications that have to be tested in both, or even developed in parallel).

The problem I'm having is that if I want to commit something from one of the clones and have it ready in the other, I have to upload it to the repo from one clone, and then download it again in the other.

I'd want to have a solution to avoid that unnecessary upload, maybe having some kind of local synchronization between the two clones.

One workaround would be to use git worktrees, but as **worktrees won't let me checkout the same branch in both clones**, I have to checkout to another branch in one clone and then checkout again the other clone to the branch I'm working on, which is not so straightforward.

Is this I'm asking possible in any other easier way?

Comment: You need to set up additional remotes so that you can see the clones themselves without having to resort to pushing to another remote. `git help remote`... you could also consider using 2 worktrees on one of the local repos so that you do not need to hold 2 separate local repos. `git help worktree`.

Comment: I feel you need to solve this problem with build script configuration rather than git. Most of the build scripts do have provision to define variants to manage which files get included into each build variant. It will simplify your development and release process.

Comment: I would also suggest using worktrees. The only prevented action is to checkout the active branch of the other worktrees, but you can choose actions that don't : `cherry-pick`, `merge other/branch`, `rebase` with the right parameters, `git checkout -b tmp other/branch` ...

Comment: @eftshift0 thanks for your answer! If I'm understanding you correctly, I can set one of the clones to be the remote of another and then push from one to other?

Comment: you got that one right!

Comment: @Mohana Rao thanks for your answer! I'll investigate that.

Comment: @eftshift0 good I'll try then. Thanks!

Comment: @LeGEC you are right, I didn't think about that, specifically the last suggestion (tmp branch) looks quite easy. Thanks!